# question about the basis of order topology

Tags: general-topology

recently I read the order topology and the basis element,I have a question that if (a,b)$\cap$(c,d)=$\emptyset $,but $\emptyset $is not belongs to any basis elements(ie. (a,b) for a<b),why it can be basis?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the condition:

$$\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2 : \exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$$

If $B_1 \cap B_2$ are empty, the statement is already true because we have a quantor $\forall$ over the empty set! See [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

You can formulate this condition equivalently as: the intersection of any two basic elements is a *union* of a family of basic elements, and then it works too as the empty set is the result of the empty union (the union of the empty subfamily of the base).

Comment: what is a "quantor ∀" means?

Comment: also does the empty set is  the basis element?

Comment: I know you means in "logic", if the codition is false then no matter the result is true or false,it always be true      Is this your meaning?

Comment: and also it is truely although no basis  element such that  B3⊆∅  it also be hold? since we are in empty set?

Comment: @RiYang $\forall$ is “for all”. The empty set is not in the base.

Comment: @RiYang If the intersection is empty we don't have any points at all for which to find $B_3$, the condition is void and thus automatically true. No work to be done. So in checking the condition we can always assume (WLOG) we have an $x$ in the intersection and prove it for that case.